# Spark: Extract dataframe from logical plan

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, sql-execution-plan

This line of code converts a dataFrame to a logical plan

```
val logical = df.queryExecution.logical
```

Can we do the opposite, meaning extracting from the logical plan, the dataframes used ?

Comment: when you say the dataframes used, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I need to take an input a logical plan and retrieve from this plan the table or the dataframe used to execute the query

Comment: The logical plan describes how Spark will process the data, but doesn't contain the data that was processed. So, unless I'm misunderstanding, the answer to your question is no, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

in Dataset object there is a method:

```
def ofRows(sparkSession: SparkSession, logicalPlan: LogicalPlan)
```

so if you have a logical plan, you can transform it into a DataFrame by calling `Dataset.ofRows(sparkSession, logical)`