# Implications of getting Dataframe from Logical Plan in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing some custom additions to SparkSQL and in some places, I require a reference to Dataframe.

I've already checked questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763246/spark-extract-dataframe-from-logical-plan), and I know that Logical Plans can be converted to data frame by `Dataset.ofRows(Sqlctx, Plan)`.

My question is more about the implications of this like will this conversion trigger a job/ data scan? I'm not performing any explicit action on this data frame, just chaining it through some more transformations.

Please help me here, and let me know if any more details are required.

Comment: Well... Have you tried it out, and what was the result?

Comment: @mazaneicha i'm not sure how I can check if the data is being scanned, logs?

Comment: You can see the jobs in Spark UI. It also shows the size of Input and Output, at the job  summary and for individual stages.